# Translation with simultaneous animated rotation of view does not stay at anchor point

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a gray view that can be moves around the screen.
The gray view has a child view (think of it as a clock hand) that rotates with an animation.
The angle at which the child view rotates correlates directly to the `translation` value which the parent view uses for its `.offset()` or `.position`.

Even though I am only trying to animate the `.rotationEffect()` of the child view, it does not stay at it's anchor position.

[image]

In the example below, the gray view can be moved with a drag gesture or buttons at the bottom of the screen, and the child view rotates counter-clockwise if the gray view moves up, and clockwise if it moves down.

Without the `.animation()` property in the child view, it rotates properly.

[Here is a Xcode Playground](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oncey2w78e9ybjc/RotationTranslation.playground?dl=0) of the issue with the code below:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var translation: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            movingView()
                .overlay(rotatingView(), alignment: .top)
                .overlay(anchorPoint())
                .offset(translation)
                .gesture(dragGesture())
            
            controls()
        }
    }
}

private extension Example {
    
    func rotatingView() -> some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 4.0, height: 50.0)
            .rotationEffect(angle, anchor: .bottom)
            .animation(.interactiveSpring(), value: angle)
    }
    
    var angle: Angle {
        let total = translation.height
        return .degrees(total)
    }
    
}

private extension Example {
    
    func movingView() -> some View {
        Color.gray
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    }
    
    func dragGesture() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                self.translation = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.translation = .zero
            }
    }
    
}

private extension Example {
    func anchorPoint() -> some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 8.0, height: 8.0)
    }
}

private extension Example {
    func controls() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button("Up") {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        translation.height -= 100
                    }
                }
                
                Button("Down") {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        translation.height += 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(
    rootView: Example()
        .frame(width: 500.0, height: 800.0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding a `drawingGroup()` modifier after `.overlay(anchorPoint())`, e.g.

```
ZStack {
    movingView()
        .overlay(rotatingView(), alignment: .top)
        .overlay(anchorPoint())
        .drawingGroup()
        .offset(translation)
        .gesture(dragGesture())
    
    controls()
}
```

[image]

This composites the view’s contents into an offscreen image before final display.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview/drawinggroup(opaque:colormode:)